# Using Kharitonov method to design the Robust controller for uncertain model

Tags: matlab, math, controls

The tr. functions describing the system.

```
G11= 1 / (29s^3 + 40s^2 + 30s +20), G12= 1 / (50s^3 + 10s^2 + 70s +2),
G21= 1 / (80s^3 + 10s^2 + 90s +5), G22= 1 / (11s^3 + 4s^2 + 66s +7),
```

then,
Can I consider it as an uncertain plants given by **`Gij= 1/ (a s^3 + bs^2 + c s + d )`** where,

```
a min = 11, a max = 80; b min =4 , b max = 40,
c min = 30, c max = 90, d min = 2, d max = 20.
```

How can we apply Kharitonov theorem to design a PID controller for an uncertain system described transfer functions and plot the interval stable region?

Comment: As far as I know, Kharitonov's theorem is to ascertain the robust stability of a system. I don't think there is any way of designing a PID controller using that. 
If you have found a solution by now, please post it here. :)